# Trying to remove a large folder from git repo but taking too long

Tags: linux, git, large-files

I have a git repo that has a folder with about 70,000 files in it. This has been a pain so instead of using the 70,000 files I have compressed them into one tar.gz.

I'm now trying to remove the directory from the git repo, but it seems to be taking a LOT longer than I would think. I'm wondering if git is just hanging every time I try to remove the folder.

I do see git running when I do an `htop`:

[image: process using running]

This is the command I am using to remove the folder:

`git rm -r <folder_name>`

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update:  It eventually did finish, took about 20 mins.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way would be to separate the index update (recording the deletion) from the filesystem actual deletion:

```
 git rm -r --cached <folder_name> 
 rm -Rf <folder_name>
 git commit -m "delete folder"
```